# What is the keyboard shortcut to collapse current region in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

By "current region" I mean a region where the cursor is.

**EDIT:** I am looking for **region** toggling, not **outlining expansion** toggling. By "region" I mean section of code defined by `#region` and `#endregion` directives. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> toggles closest outlining (which for most cases would be current method not region).

Comment: I dont think there is a shortcut for this, but I would love to be proven wrong if anyone can find one or a way to create it.

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> should do the trick

By the way you can download a "poster" of shortcuts [here](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/)

Comment: The second M also has to have a CTRL modifier

Comment: @JaredPar I was assuming that person would realize that you hold down the control as usual when using shortcuts

Comment: @JohnM2 Your welcome! Keyboard shortcuts are so essential. I dont know what I would do without them.

Comment: Poster link is no longer good. [try this for VS 2015](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/)

Comment: @Josh Not sure how it was in 2010, but these days it's not uncommon to run into a shortcut that doesn't involve holding down ctrl.

Answer (score 2):

It can differ from mapping to mapping but the default is :
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010 use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.  I did not check Visual Studio 2008